# Android Image View Animation leaving behind trail

Tags: android, android-animation

I am animating an ImageView from the center of the screen to the top-left using an Animation Set.I am Translating and Scaling the View.

Heres the code snippet.

```
        AnimationSet tempAnimation=new AnimationSet(true);

        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0,xPos, 0, yPos );


        anim.setFillAfter( true );
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);


        ScaleAnimation scaleanimation = new ScaleAnimation(1, (float)0.22, 1, (float)0.22, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
        scaleanimation.setDuration(1000); 
        scaleanimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        scaleanimation.setFillAfter(true);

        tempAnimation.addAnimation(scaleanimation);
        tempAnimation.addAnimation(anim);
        tempAnimation.setDuration(1000);

      // This takes care that the ImageViews stay in their final positions after animating . 
        tempAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        tempAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

        mimageView.startAnimation(tempAnimation);
```

So,the problem is that it is leaving behind a trail /previous positions for just a brief moment.But it doesnt look good or smooth.I have noticed that if I use only 1 animation it is fine but using the animation set causes the trail.Are there any tips to avoid this?

Cheers

Comment: hii... Have you try to decrease the setDuration(1000); to setDuration(100); may be it take little time because of this . try it and reply me if it is a solution.

Comment: Thanks Mit,Changing the duration does make it to look better.Unfortunately,I need the duration to be one second.I did find a solution.Check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer eventually at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22151.

Scale and Translation Animations have a problem on Android 2.3 .The simplest way to fix this is to add a small transparent padding around the image.In the code shown above,Just add

```
mimageView.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
```

Works like a charm!